# Why react native FlatList empty?

Tags: react-native

I use react native. I need render a lot of images in FlatList. I use

```
return (
        <View style={styles.main}>
            {!fetchingImages ? (
                <FlatList
                    containerContentStyle={[{alignSelf: 'stretch'}]}
                    data={images}
                    renderItem={({item}) => (
                        <ImageCard item={item}/>
                    )}
                    keyExtractor={item => generateKey(item.id)}

                    // Performance settings
                    removeClippedSubviews={true} // Unmount components when outside of window

                />
            ) : (
                <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff"/>
            )}
        </View>
    );
```

Then screen loading it empty, but if I starting scrolling, FlatList starts showing up.
Where i have mistake?

Comment: Please share the ImageCard code as well. There is a problem in the ImageCard

Comment: Add `extraData={this.state}` props in your Flatlist.